# Define a command containing a sequence of commands in texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I have `texmaker-1.9.9` and because of some patches, i can't update it. For building my document without any bug or problem, I should do this scenario twice (1->2->1->2):

1. Run a command for creating glossary (defined in user commands)
2. Quick Build -> Bibtex Build -> Quick Build -> Bibtex Build

Is there any way in `texmaker` to define a command for executing the whole scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the image below. It shows the Configure Options for Quick Build. You can use personal commands and I'm sure that the shortcut for Quick Build is `F1`.

Go to Options menu and configure it.

[image]

Another image (maybe other version). Note the commands separated by `|`.

[image]

Comment: My glossary command (defined in user commands) is too long, is it possible to add it to quick build, by referencing that user command?

Comment: You can add shortcuts for all.